# Interrupting chained animation in SVG (using Webkit)

Tags: svg, webkit, mobile-webkit

I am using SVG to display chained animations (each path automatically starts when the previous path is complete) and managed to make it work fine. I even worked in a 'refresh' element that resets the animation chain.

My problem, is that I want to provide a way to 'skip' the animation. It is easy to add an element that triggers `<set>` elements to display the paths without animation, however this does not stop the animation chain, which keeps going through each element (resetting and re-drawing them).

**I need a *WebKit-supported* way to stop a chained SVG animation...**

Things I tried:

- Setting an `end` attribute on the `<animate>` element that gets triggered by `skip.click`: stops the animation of the current stroke, but still fires `end` events and therefore doesn't stop the chain.
- Setting the `begin` attributes to `indefinite` and manually triggering the animation of the next path at the end of each path. However, this would require the ability to execute code on `onend` in the `<animate>` element, which WebKit apparently does not support yet.
- Finding any way to stop ongoing animations (without triggering an `end` event), but references for current versions of SVG do not seem to give any (I have seen it listed as a problem to solve, in a presentation on drafting future versions of SVG/SMIL).

I was hoping anybody had figured a workaround of some kind to this problem. I figure I must not be the first person to want a chain of animations with a 'restart' and 'skip' buttons...

For reference, here is a simplified example of the type of SVG code I am using (generated on-the-fly by a program, so possibly not as compact as could be):

```xml
<svg width="220" height="220" viewBox="0 0 109 109" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1"  baseProfile="full">  
    <path d="M33.28,19.04c1.84,0.71,3.7,0.86,5.4,0.63c4.95-0.67,27.95-4.58,29.86-4.92c3.46-0.62,4.06,1.36,2.11,3.58c-1.95,2.22-11.41,13.17-16.35,17.19" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(230,71,71);stroke-width:3" stroke-dasharray="67.00,67.00" stroke-dashoffset="67.00" stroke-linecap="round">
        <animate id="step0" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="67.00;0" dur="1.3s" begin="0.10;refresh.click+0.01" fill="freeze" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1" calcMode="spline" />
        <set attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" to="67.00" begin="refresh.click" /> 
    </path> 
    <path d="M52.48,37.74c6.42,2.97,11.75,30.73,5.24,52.57c-2.8,9.38-8.09,2.96-10.47,0.99" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(230,71,71);stroke-width:3" stroke-dasharray="70.00,70.00" stroke-dashoffset="70.00" stroke-linecap="round">
        <animate id="step1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="70.00;0" dur="1.4s" begin="step0.end+0.1s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1" calcMode="spline" />
        <set attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" to="70.00" begin="refresh.click" /> 
    </path> 
    <path d="M12.25,51.48c3.75,1.14,8.79,1.03,12.48,0.49c16.77-2.47,42.86-5.84,58.53-6.75c4.26-0.25,9.11-0.34,13.11,0.57" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(230,71,71);stroke-width:3" stroke-dasharray="85.00,85.00" stroke-dashoffset="85.00" stroke-linecap="round">
        <animate id="step2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="85.00;0" dur="1.7s" begin="step1.end+0.1s" fill="freeze" keySplines="0.5 0 0.5 1" calcMode="spline" />
        <set attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" to="85.00" begin="refresh.click" /> 
    </path> 
    <g id="skipAnimation" visibility="visible"> <set  attributeName="visibility" begin="step2.end" end="refresh.click" to="hidden"/> 
        <text id="skip" x="95" y="105" stroke="#AAA" stroke-width="0.5" style="font-size:11px;">➠</text>
    </g>
    <g id="animationDone" visibility="hidden"> <set  attributeName="visibility" begin="step2.end" end="refresh.click" to="visible"/> 
        <text id="refresh" x="95" y="105" stroke="#AAA" stroke-width="0.5" style="font-size:11px;">↻</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```